# Why require at least 6 characters when improving answer?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I saw an answer to a question on this site, which I found difficult to read, due to the author not having split the text in to proper sections.

So I simply added the paragraphs, where it made sense. But was unable to save the change, since the change was less than 6 characters long. This tricked me, because the change was a real improvement to readability. The content was actually fine, so I did not want to alter the wording only the readability of the post.

Why prevent people from doing that?

Comment: I guess it's a measure to prevent trolls or bots to make useless changes, and prevent rep-miners from making single-digit typo corrections in the hopes these changes are acknowledged by reviewers delivering them easy rep.

Comment: @AliceD I think that it will encourage users, who want to modify minor errors such as greatly improving readability by adding line breaks, from improving questions/answers, or worse, add changes that were not required to the answer. The rep-miners will easily be able to add 6 characters that add no value what so ever.

Comment: Don't understand me wrong, I'm not advocating it, it's only a likely explanation. The same goes for commenting - the minimum required words is a nuisance as well.

Comment: Do they not have the same requirement on other stack exchange sites?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149771/legitimate-edits-of-less-than-6-characters https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81895/6-character-long-edits-hack Since this a sitewide policy your question would be better on the main meta rather than here, nothing special about Biology.SE on this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It only applies to peer-reviewed edits.  Once you reach the edit posts threshold (2,000), you can make edits of any size, and you don't need an edit summary.

It's almost definitely a measure to prevent people from loading the queues (which are already loaded enough on some sites) with tiny edits.

The best practice (and one I do fairly frequently) is on sites where you're under 2k, simply drop a comment to the OP mentioning the issue.  90% of the time they edit it themselves.  Just keep an eye on the post so you can remove the comment once it's done.

See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77257/372269) from Jeff Atwood and the links Bryan Krause shared for more info.